# insert into select - stored procedure affects 0 rows

Tags: select, stored-procedures, insert

I am using SQL Server 2014. I created a stored procedure to update a table, but when i run this it affects 0 rows. i'm expecting to see 501 rows affected, as the actual insert statement when run alone returns that.The table beingupdated is pre-populated.

I also tried pre-populating the table with 500 records to see if the last 1 row was pulled by the stored procedure, but it still affects 0 rows.

```
Create PROCEDURE UPDATE_STAGING 
    (@StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = '')  
   AS  
      BEGIN  
        IF @StatementType = 'Insertnew'  
            BEGIN  
                INSERT INTO owner.dbo.MVR_Staging  
                  (
                    policy_number, 
                    quote_number,
                    request_id,
                    CreateTs,
                    mvr_response_raw_data
                 )  
               select 
                  p.pol_num, 
                  A.pol_number,
                  R.Request_ID, 
                  R.CreateTS, 
                  R._raw_data
               from TABLE1 A with (NOLOCK)
               left join TABLE2 R with  (NOLOCK)
                 on R.Request_id = isnull(A.CACHE_REQUEST_ID, A.Request_id)
               inner join TABLE3 P
                 on p.quote_policy_num = a.policy_number
               where  
                 A.[SOURCE] = 'MVR'
                 and A.CREATED_ON >= '2020-01-01'
      END  
    IF @StatementType = 'Select'  
         BEGIN  
           SELECT *  
         FROM   owner.dbo.MVR_Staging  
     END  
END
```

to run:

```
exec  UPDATE_STAGING insertnew
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Some correction to your code that is not related to your issue, but is good to keep a best practice and clean code.When declaring a `stored procedure` parameter, there's no point using parenthesis  `(@StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = '')`. Also you should be using `ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Select'`, without `ELSE`, this second `IF` condition will always be checked. Execute the procedure `exec  UPDATE_STAGING 'insertnew'`, as the parameter is `NVARCHAR`. As for your real issue, you could try comment the `INSERT` part and leave only the `SELECT` to see if rows are returned.